# Is a No Objection Certificate really needed when applying for a UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-of-employment

I am from India and I am planning to visit London to meet my friends. I am working in a private company in India.

In the employment proof, they are asking for a letter from my employer on headed paper - detailing my salary and the length of the employment, confirming that I have been give time off work and asked me to state whether this time off is paid or unpaid.

My company's HR are ready to give employment proof, but not the info related to time off work. Is it mandatory?

Is the No Objection Certificate really needed for the persons who are working in private sector companies. I heard that it is needed only for people who are working in government sectors. Kindly confirm this too.

Comment: What is a COC? Can you explain it / expand the acronym / give a reference?

Comment: It might be "certificate of competency" and I think it's a separate question from the one about whether UKVI requires info on whether time off work is granted and paid/unpaid.

Comment: Why is your company unwilling to state that you have been given time off work? Have they agreed to give you time off work? If not, how are you going to make the trip?

Comment: Do as you've been told, provide the certificate and you'll be fine.

Comment: They have agreed to give time off work. But they wont give details, whether i am paid or unpaid during my time off work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a long-standing principle at UKVI to avoid stipulating that a given piece of evidence is mandatory; it means the guidelines are *purposefully vague*. As spelled out in the [Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk), the only *mandatory* requirements are...

- A 'valid' passport or some other 'valid' identity document (but
  'valid' is vague)
- The fee

From that law they created a *policy* that the passport be *current* with a blank page and that it be accompanied by a photo.

Everything else is expressed with modal verbs, most often "should" and "may".  Having said all of that, let's look at your question...

**My company's HR are ready to give employment proof, but not the info related to time off work. Is it mandatory?**

While not mandatory it is a great idea to include something that shows you have accrued enough holiday for your visit.  Lots of people on the Indian subcontinent interpret this as a No Objection Certificate (NOC) or a variant document and it has vectored on the net as a requirement.

- Your employment contract should spell out your holiday entitlement,
  include it.
- Your salary slips should list your unspent entitlement, include them.
  If they do not show your unspent entitlement, find something else
  that does.

If the above will not work for one reason or another, you can make a *personal attestation* about your unspent entitlement. You need good credibility in order for that to work and you will need to explain why that info isn't in any of your employment documents.

**I heard that it is needed only for people who are working in government sectors. Kindly confirm this too.**

There is no reason to confirm or deny it; as explained, the concept of a *requirement* is simply one that has vectored on the net. Any other sort of evidence is fine. Note that NOC's are fairly unique to the subcontinent anyway.

We can take a look at the [guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf) itself.  Examine the screen shot...

[image]

Based on this, it is safe to conclude that your company is providing what UKVI wants to see.

And finally, from your question: **"...confirming that I have been give time off work and asked me to state whether this time off is paid or unpaid..."**

This appears to be something you added independently (probably somewhere on the net having to do with Indian nationals); sometimes it's great to include that information, but it is absolutely not mandatory.

Comment: Thank you very much ! My company have provided me a document which says that I have been time off work from x date to y date.
I will be submitting my Payslips as well as bank statements as a part of proof to unspent entitlement.
Thank you very much for your valuable information :)

Comment: @Sam all part of the service, please be real sure to read all of the related questions/answers on the site. They can be helpful!

Comment: @Sam something I forgot, you can ask a new question if there's any advisories for Indian nationals applying for a UK visa.

Comment: Yeah I have read, still I cant be sure of those as I am travelling for the very first time. 
Thanks for the second suggestion!

Comment: I have one more doubt. No where I could see about taking a medical insurance for the Tourist visit. Is that mandatory while applying for VISA ?

Comment: @Sam, easy to answer but please respect the site rules and ask a new question.  Thanks!