# The Belgian consulate requests a guarantee letter from my wife's employer. What documents can I supply instead?

Tags: visas, schengen, belgium, proof-of-employment

I have applied for Family visit visa to Belgium as my wife working there. I have provided all the details like my employer letter, return ticket. Still consulate asking for a Guarantee letter from wife's employer stating my return. Company refused to give. What to be done?

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate, as it refers to UK visas, not Schengen): http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65253/is-a-no-objection-certificate-really-needed-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa

Comment: Why would your wife's company in Belgium need to give any guarantees about your immigration and return? Or want to - would that make them responsible for deporting you if you overstayed?

Comment: That's what I asked them but telling they require it

Comment: There must be some misunderstanding here then. Can you find out from the consulate precisely what they want the Belgian company to guarantee? It may be something like they confirm you're not entering the country to seek employment with them, and that they won't give it, or that they pay your wife enough money that between you you can reasonably fund your stay (although I can't imagine that's it). Once you have something more specific you can hopefully take that to the company and convince them.

Comment: They have asked my wife's company should give letter of guarantee for my return back to India after expiry of my visa. Its self funding case so they dont have any doubt in that

Comment: @Shiv: You'll probably need to quote the _exact wording_ of what you've been told by the consulate -- your own paraphrase sounds so strange that readers will tend to assume _you_ have misunderstood it. Quoting what you have been told verbatim will make it easier for us to make heads or tails of it,

Comment: FWIW, Every embassy in Doha ask for the employer/sponser's NOC Letter, stating Salary, Joining Date, Leave Dates, Visit Purpose & " Guarantee" to return, but companies just write " X is expected to resume his duties from abc date".

Comment: @Shiv, to get the highest quality answer, you should include the exact text of what the consulate told you. It is impossible for a 3rd party to 'guarantee' your return, they can state your commitments, and guarantee your maintenance, but who can 'guarantee' your return if you do not want to return?

Comment: You do not even state what country you are *from*

Comment: I am from India. The Belgium Consulate sent a letter requesting a document. And they state as follows : "Provide a letter of Guarantee from AAAAAAA mentioning you will return to India upon expiry of your Visa". That AAAAAAA is my wife's employer. Already I have submitted NOC and letter of leave sanction from my employer

Comment: That request doesn't make sense. It is not possible for some company with no relation to you to guarantee your return to India. I suspect that the consulate does not understand the purpose of your visit, and perhaps they think that AAAAAA is your employer.