# Traveling Paris during my summer vacation, Do I still need NOC?

Tags: paperwork, france, schengen-visas, applications, proof-of-employment

My husband and I are planning to visit Paris in July. We are both working in school, and during June-July there's no work. I'm confused if do we still need to get an NOC since those months are summer vacation. It would be weird to file for leave when there's actually no work. Thank you! :)

Comment: Do you have a document that shows there is no work during June and July and that you will return to work in August?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe an NOC is ever needed?

Comment: You should probably clarify what an NOC is.

Answer (score 1):

VFS Global in India appear to have made a No Objection Certificate mandatory:

No Objection certificate is required for the following categories

- Children under the age of 18 needs to have it from both the parents.
- In case of one parent traveling along with the child, NOC from the other parent is mandatory.
- An employee working with an organization needs to have a NOC or a leave sanction details from the concerned department /office

Source is the VFS Global FAQs for an application to the Netherlands but they apply it for all Schengen and UK applications AFAIK, and probably across the board

http://www.vfsglobal.com/netherlands/india/faqs.html

The OP specifically asked about France, however for reference see also [Is a No Objection Certificate really needed when applying for a UK visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65253/is-a-no-objection-certificate-really-needed-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa)

Comment: How can VFS make things mandatory like that? They're not involved with deciding applications.

Comment: @Henning Makholm I agree. Although perhaps a means to standardise proof of employment rather than have applicants rejected for not providing the required information.